# Create a view with checkboxes per role, that generates an email to an admin

Tags: emails, views

I want a registered user to be able to tick rows in a table, and then submit an email to a predefined email address containing the titles of the selected rows.

VBO almost does what I want - in that there is a "send email" option, but on clicking the button it displays a form to be filled in with email address, title subject etc to send the email - I don't want that, I want it just to send a single email when the user clicks the button containing the titles of the selected rows.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Views Send](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_send) module, you may try this.

[Views Send](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_send) enables you to send mass mailing from a View.

This module support tokens and Global: Send E-mail with VBO.

Comment: Yes I saw that, but as I understand it it sends an email to the email addresses from a column in a view. That's not what I want - I want to send a single email containing the selected rows.

Comment: Try writing custom action for VOB https://www.drupal.org/node/2052067

Comment: Thanks. I try wherever possible to avoid writing custom stuff for Drupal - it seems to defeat the purpose of using Drupal in the first place. There are so many different ways to do things with Drupal I always try to find a method that doesn't need custom code.